# JS file share between front end as common file and backend as module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, server-side, client-side

A JS file name `list.js` contains an array of data like:

```
let users = [{firstname: 'Paul', lastname:'smith'}];
```

This file is loaded on client side with the following line:

```
<script src="/js/list.js"></script>
```

Therefore the same file must also be loaded in a module on server side (in node.js).

```
require('../public/js/list.js');
```

Since this is in a module, I can't use `require`. I have to use import:

```
import { users } from '../public/js/list.js';
```

On the other hand, if I export my variable, I can no longer load the file on client side:

```
export var users = [{firstname: 'Paul', lastname:'smith'}];
```

Is there a trick to load the file on both client and server side?

---

EDIT: If I use the following in the file `list.js`

```
module.exports = [{firstname: 'Paul', lastname:'smith'}];
```

I have to use require in my node.js module:

```
const { users } = require('../public/js/list.js');
```

It does not work:

```
module.exports = [{firstname: 'Paul', lastname:'smith'}];
```

With the second option, `export` can't be placed in a test:

```
if (true) export default testList;
```

I've go the following error:

```
if (true) export default users;
          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: You can check whether the environment supports `require`, `module` or `export` and only then use it.

Comment: @jabaa Thx, therefore, I'm not sure to understand how to do this? Few lines of code should help me started

Comment: This is how jQuery handles it: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js Most transpilers automatically add this boilerplate code. Check for ComminJs: `if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" )`. Check for `window`: `typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this`

Comment: You could switch to ESM and then use that both browser-side ande in Node.js. That's one of the advantages of JavaScript having a standard module system now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I'm already to ESM. Could you detail your suggestion?

Comment: @Fifi - Not if you're using `require`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules (or Chapter 13 in my book).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder => ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead. I just edited the question.

Comment: @Fifi - That was my point. You've shown you're using `require` (and `module.exports`). That isn't ESM.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That was to explain what I already try and does not work.

Comment: I guess your test suite is running in Node.js with CommonJS. You can either change the module system for the test suite or apply my comment.

Comment: @jabaa In package.json => "type": "module", is already configured

Comment: Maybe your test suite doesn't support ESM. Maybe you have to configure something else. Impossible to say without more details.

Comment: @jabaa, what do you need?

Comment: What test suite do you use? How do you test your code?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS / node.js v18.15.0 Is it what you mean by test suite?

Comment: You wrote you got errors in your tests. What tests?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little trick.

You can use nodejs detection to do that.
See the following.

```
let users = [{firstname: 'Paul', lastname:'smith'}]; // Your variable

if (typeof process === 'object') { // Detect when this is nodejs
    // Expose the users variable
    module.exports.users = users;
}
```

That should work broswer-side.
On your nodejs side:

```
const { users } = require('../public/js/list.js');
```

Hope that helps.
Regards.

Comment: The requested module '../public/js/list.js' does not provide an export named 'users'

Comment: Hum, when I use  `export default users;` if works, but as soon I place it in the test, I've got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: @Fifi You cannot put `export` inside of `if` because `export` is meant to be analyzed statically (without running the code).

Comment: So, what I meant to do is not  possible?

Comment: so you have tried the import statement?